# On gitlab CI: "fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

On gitlab CI job that runs on merge requests, I do:

```
git rev-list master..branch_name
```

I expect to have the list of SHAs in branch_name and` not in master. But I get the error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..branch_name': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

The `master` and `branch_name` are correct. The command is working when run against my local repo.

Any idea why? and how to work around that?

Comment: It's clear that your GitLab repo (the one used for CI, not the *main* repo but rather the clone of that one) *does not* have both branch names. The rest ... is less clear, since I don't actually use GitLab.

Comment: Given the error wording, yes I believe so. But I'm lacking the knowledge on GitLab and was wondering why is it the case if the repo is cloned by GitLab.

Comment: Just as a general rule, a lot of CI systems make shallow and/or single-branch clones (with `--depth` and `--single-branch` arguments to `git clone`). These both cause problems here. If you have an easy way to turn that off, that's an easy way around this problem. These CI systems do that, though, so as to avoid making a full clone, which is slower and needs more space: they don't just do it to break builds. You're left with the problem of figuring out how to balance these issues.

Comment: thnx @torek. you are right. I did `git fetch --depth 50 origin master:master` and `git fetch --depth 50 origin branch_name:branch_name` before my `git rev-list ...` and it worked. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: There's probably some better way, but that depends on the GitLab tools.

Comment: @kdehairy This does look like a neat answer

Answer (score 5):

Gitlab CI makes shallow copies by default. Check project settings >
CI/CD Settings > Git strategy:

- `git clone` slow
- `git fetch` with optional `--depth` argument

However if you specify that you want to run this stage only for `merge_requests` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, e.g.:

```
test:
  script:
    - git diff-tree --name-only --no-commit-id -r ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA}..${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

a set of [special environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines) will be included in the CI job. Then you should be able to use e.g. `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA` as a reference for the target branch without the need to checkout the whole repository.

The branch for `merge_requests` pipeline is called e.g. `refs/merge-requests/1` instead of e.g. `branch_name`.

In order to change the `fetch/clone` behavior use:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  GIT_DEPTH: 0       # fetch all branches, might be slow
```